# How to add a callback function to the addClass method of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm using Prettify from Google and Markdown and I want each time I find a `pre` code added in the markdown `textarea` to call again the `prettyPrint()` function.

This is my actual code:

```
if($('#wmd-preview').length > 0) {
  $('#wmd-preview').on('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved',function(){
    $(this).find("pre").not('.prettyprint').addClass("prettyprint");
  });
}
```

But I want something like:

```
$(this).find("pre").not('.prettyprint').addClass("prettyprint",function(){
  prettyPrint();
});
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: What would the callback do? When should it be called?

Comment: You can see the second example. The callback will call the function prettyPrint() which add style to the code inserted in the markdown preview. It should be called each time is found a new `pre` element without a `prettyprint` css class. I don't want to call it each time is rased the `domnodeinserted` or `domnoderemoved` events, but only in the case described above.

Comment: There is no callback for addClass. Are you saying that you want to run prettyPrint after each single pre got a `prettyprint` class?

Comment: @MateiMihai You could overwrite the `addClass` function with your own that will fire a custom event (but that won't help here, so...)

Comment: `It should be called each time is found a new pre element without a prettyprint` Do you mean that it should happen when new `pre` element is added to a DOM?

Comment: @FAngel yep. That's what he wants.

Comment: @FAngel I know there is no callback for addClass. yes, I want to run it after each pre element found without a prettyprint class, but after I'm adding it that class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need this:

```
$(this).find("pre").not('.prettyprint').each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("prettyprint");
   prettyPrint();
})
```

Answer (score 19):

You could extend `.addClass()` jquery's method to let it accept a callback function:

```
;(function ($) {
    var oAddClass = $.fn.addClass;
    $.fn.addClass = function () {
        for (var i in arguments) {
            var arg = arguments[i];
            if ( !! (arg && arg.constructor && arg.call && arg.apply)) {
                setTimeout(arg.bind(this));
                delete arguments[i];
            }
        }
        return oAddClass.apply(this, arguments);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Then use it as usual:

```
 $('pre:not(.prettyprint)').addClass('prettyprint',prettyPrint);
```

Comment: This is great, except that it adds `.prettyprint` after the callback is executed. Callbacks are supposed to be fired after the core event has completed (such as with [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)).

Comment: @jacob Updated it to push callback in event queue and to set relevant callback context, thx!

Answer (score 2):

The `addClass` jQuery function doesn't have a callback in arguments.

Read more about this in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

I think that this sould work for you:

```
// prettyprint class is added
$(this).find("pre").not('.prettyprint').addClass("prettyprint");
// after prettyprint class is added, prettyPrint function is called
prettyPrint();
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use this solution because the prettyPrint() function will be called each time you type any charachter in the markdown container, which is not what I want..