# Callback function on addClass not working

Tags: jquery

I want the browser to focus on the input after clicking the focus button.

But before that I want it to add a class first and then focus. Is this possible? Or can I only use callback functions on 'animations' like hide, click etc.

I've created a jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ktgc4h9/5/

```
$('.input').hide();

$('.focus').click(function()
{
    $('.input').show();

  $('input').addClass('test', function()
  {
        $('.search').focus();
  });
})
```

Comment: There is no `.search` element in your code...? Which element are you trying to target? Also note that in plain jQuery `addClass()` does not have a callback - it's a synchronous function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14568870/1449710

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.addClass` doesn't *have* a callback function.](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Callbacks are used for asynchronous operations.  They aren't needed for synchronous operations.  Just execute the code in the order you want it executed:

```
$('input').addClass('test');
$('.search').focus();
```

Comment: The jQueryUI version of addClass does have a callback parameter - but I agree it's redundant here in any case

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan UI is not mentioned

Comment: @Alex I know, but OP may be using it without the thought that it was relevant to his question.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a chain, not a callback for calling `focus`:

```
$('.input').addClass('test').focus();
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/6ktgc4h9/6/)**

You could even chain the `show()` too, if the element is all the same:

```
$('.input').show().addClass('test').focus();
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/6ktgc4h9/4/)**

Comment: Note that in OPs code, the element focused is different from the one, where the class is attached to.

Comment: But this element is not exisitng in his example, so i assume he mean the `type="search"` what would be the same element then. And even see the note `placeholder="focus here"` in the example.