# Extending jQuery addClass to accept callbacks - how does it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I am fairly new to `jQuery` and were looking for a way to extend `addClass` to accept callbacks. I found this solution [here](https://gist.github.com/gabrysiak/166befef3264d0c53f47). Here is the code part that does do the magic:

```
var oAddClass = $.fn.addClass;
$.fn.addClass = function () {
    for (var i in arguments) {
        var arg = arguments[i];
        if ( !! (arg && arg.constructor && arg.call && arg.apply)) {
            arg();
            delete arg;
        }
    }
    return oAddClass.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Can someone explain what happens here? I've got basic knowledge of programing terminology and I've already used `jQuery` for simple stuff like scroll-over ads.

Sincerely,

Nunu

Comment: Obviously, it comes from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14568870/1414562) not [there](https://gist.github.com/gabrysiak/166befef3264d0c53f47)... :)  And as a side note, this would be more relevant to use `setTimeout(arg.bind(this));` instead of `arg()`

Comment: @A.Wolff Wolff what does the `setTimeout` do in this case?

Comment: It delays callback function to execute **after** the class is added, not before as in previous posted code. `bind()` is used to set relevant context to callback method. `this` in this case is the jq matched set/obj

Comment: alright, thats good, thanks for that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it loops over all the arguments addClass was called with. If that argument is a function (found out by duck typing that the argument has a constructor and call/apply methods), it will call that function and remove it from the arguments arraylike object.

Lastly the remaining arguments, (the non-functions) are apply'ed onto the element by using the reference to the original addClass function (oAddClass), so that the real class strings are also added to the element.

As a sidenote, why would you have need for callbacks on setClass, since it's not async.

Comment: Ya, it doesn't really make sense to add a callback for sync method

Comment: Actually i wanted to make a google analytics call while one specific element gets a class that basically sets `display: none` to `display: block`. thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: And where does the array (object? variable?) `arguments` comes from? It wasn't declared anywhere as far as I can see.

Comment: It's a builtin native object that all functions have. It's an array-like structure. (has indexes, but not array methods like forEach) containing all the parameters the function was called with. It's usefull in situations where you want to overload a function. Have a look at this for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments