# Javascript Promise on JQuery addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am animating in an element which has enough content to cause the overall height of the div to be effected.

The div in question is using a [JQuery vegas background slider](https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/) to rotate through some pictures.

No I animate in the element on a click event and use the following javascript;

```
    function loadSpecification() {
        hideAll();
        $("#specification").removeClass("hidden").addClass("show", { 
            complete: function () {
                console.log("completed animation");
                loadVegas();
            }
        });
    }
```

where the loadVegas() function reloads the vegas element in order to set the slide to cover the newly expanded div.

However, the complete function is not getting fired in this instance, am I invoking it correctly? If so what going wrong here please?

My css classes are as follows;

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.show {
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    /*width: inherit;*/
}
```

Comment: I don't think that addClass has any signature with a class and a callback. I'm pretty sure it's just adding the class synchronously

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134584/how-do-i-use-transitionend-in-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a callback function to the addClass method of jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567990/how-to-add-a-callback-function-to-the-addclass-method-of-jquery)

Comment: @Alex None of the answers there mention that you need to load jQuery UI.

Comment: @Barmar because you dont.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine, remember to add jQuery UI library as the complete function is not implemented in jQuery but in jQuery UI. See [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/addclass/) for more info.

```js
 $("#specification").removeClass("hidden").addClass("show", {
   complete: function() {
     console.log("completed animation");
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="specification">test</div>
```

Comment: adding a whole library for one function is a bit overhead, isnt it?

Comment: @Alex I'm just answering a question. Overhead or not, it's not a subject of the question. I agree though, it's a huge overhead.

Comment: I was just mentioning it, no big deal :) this question has been answered so many times without the need to load jquery ui, so I just feel like this is not good practice. And its fine to say that, isnt it? :) Your aspiration should not just be to find any solution, but maybe also a good one - especially if it has been mentioned so many times before...